# Ionic 3 side bar add badge notification not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I’m using the *[*Ionic 3 - badge](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#badges)** for  for my app sidebar. i faced some conflict when i added badge but its not displayed 
anyone know how to shown badge in side bar
Thanks

my code part

**app.html**

```
   <ion-list class="user-list" >
      <button ion-item menuClose class="text-1x" *ngFor="let menuItem of appMenuItems" (click)="openPage(menuItem)" >
        <ion-icon item-left [name]="menuItem.icon" style="color: black; " ></ion-icon>
        <span ion-text style="color: black; border-bottom: none;">{{menuItem.title}}</span>
        <ion-badge">{{p.badgeCount}}</ion-badge>
      </button>
    </ion-list>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  component: any;
  icon: string;
  buttonName:string;


}


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any = SigninPage;
  selectedTheme: String;

  appMenuItems: Array<MenuItem>;


  constructor(public platform: Platform, private settings: SettingsProvider, private master: master) {

    this.settings.getActiveTheme().subscribe(val => this.selectedTheme = val);

    this.appMenuItems = [
      {title: 'Home', component: HomePage, icon: 'ios-home-outline'},

      {title: 'Notification', component: CheckoutPage, icon: 'ios-basket-outline',buttonName: 'badgeNumber ',},

    ];


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reslove the my problem

I change this      `<ion-badge>{{menuItem.badgeCount}}</ion-badge>`

**app.component.ts**

```
export interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  component: any;
  icon: string;
  buttonName:string;


}


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any = SigninPage;
  selectedTheme: String;

  appMenuItems: Array<MenuItem>;


  constructor(public platform: Platform, private settings: SettingsProvider, private master: master) {

    this.settings.getActiveTheme().subscribe(val => this.selectedTheme = val);

    this.appMenuItems = [
      {title: 'Home', component: HomePage, icon: 'ios-home-outline'},

      {title: 'Notification', component: CheckoutPage, icon: 'ios-basket-outline',badgeCount: '5 ',},

    ];


  }
```

**app.html**

```
 <ion-list class="user-list" >
      <button ion-item menuClose class="text-1x" *ngFor="let menuItem of appMenuItems" (click)="openPage(menuItem)" >
        <ion-icon item-left [name]="menuItem.icon" style="color: black; " ></ion-icon>
        <span ion-text style="color: black; border-bottom: none;">{{menuItem.title}}</span>
        <ion-badge>{{menuItem.badgeCount}}</ion-badge>
      </button>
    </ion-list>
```